# HTML5 Canvas .translate and .scale causes jagged edges on images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here's a sample: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/junerockwell/pen/xZJVYM). Just click anywhere in the canvas (it'll have black borders) and a purple star will be drawn.

As you can see, the star has jagged edges. It's drawn with `.translate` and `.scale`. To prove that `.translate` and `.scale` are causing the jagged edges, go to line 28 (in CodePen JavaScript section) and uncomment it. Then comment out line 27. When you click on the canvas, the star is drawn without `.translate` and `.scale`, but it doesn't have jagged edges.

The star was drawn in Adobe Illustrator and is exported as a 300x300px PNG.

**Update:**
I need to use `PNG`'s by the way. No `JPG`, `SVG`, etc.

**How do I fix this problem?**

---

What I've tried so far but didn't help:

1. Turned off Anti-aliasing in Adobe Illustrator's General Preferences
2. Turned off Anti-aliasing in Adobe Illustrator's Document Raster and Effects Settings
3. Used Screen 72ppi instead of 300ppi (default) in Illustrator's Document Raster and Effects Settings
4. Put a stroke (border) on the star and made this stroke have 0% opacity. I thought that it's only the border/edges that gets jagged. So, I thought that the stroke would be "invisible" that `canvas` would only make the 0% opacity stroke as jagged and therefore nothing will look jagged. But this didn't work either.
5. I've tried using these CSS suggested "hacks":

   `canvas { 
      image-rendering: crisp-edges; /* Older versions of FF */
      image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges; /* FF 6.0+ */
      image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Safari */
      image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges; /* OS X & Windows Opera (12.02+) */
      /*image-rendering: pixelated;  // Awesome future-browsers */
      image-rendering: optimize-contrast;
      -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor; /*IE*/
    }`
6. I've also tried using this JavaScript "hack":

   `context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = true;
    context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = true;
    context.imageSmoothingEnabled = true; /// future`

---

**Note:** I've tried all the code that's in Codepen locally on Safari, Firefox and Chrome before adding them all in Codepen.

Comment: You're scaling bitmap data. No easy way to get rid of those jagged edges. Can you draw the star as vector instead of using bitmap data?

Comment: Start with a larger .png and scale it down to begin with so it will scale up with less distortion. BTW, you can scale both html5 canvas & svg paths with little distortion.

Comment: I agree with markE, For this shape use context drawing operations. Also imagesmoothingenabled defaults to true, you probably wanted to set it to false.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the star to vector it will solve the problem.

```
star_img.src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="300px" height="275px" viewBox="0 0 300 275" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><polygon fill="#fdff00" stroke="#605a00" stroke-width="15" points="150,25  179,111 269,111 197,165 223,251  150,200 77,251  103,165 31,111 121,111" /></svg>';
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyBGMv

Comment: Hi @mkaatman, thanks. But 1. I've refrained in using svg's bec. I'll be using the same .src url in an <img/> tag (in a pop-up window) which I defined as having a style property of width and height. By setting the width and height, the variable being drawn in the canvas gets scaled down very tiny. This only happens in Safari and it's just lesser known Safari bug. 2. I opened your CodePen and nothing is drawn. 3. I've tried using `SVG` before and the jagged edges were there too.

Comment: BTW, html5 Canvas drawing commands are really vector commands that are drawn to the canvas drawing surface as a pseudo-bitmap (SVG does the same: issue vectors & render to screen on bitmap). So, you can scale+draw with little distortion just like with SVG. ;-)

Comment: I've updated the codepen. I don't know if it will work for safari, but supposedly if you preload the SVG in a hidden div safari can use inline SVG. Otherwise, you'd need to draw the star directly in canvas.

Comment: @junerockwell could you point to something about this bug? For drawing an svg onto a canvas you need to set the svg document 'a width and height to absolute values (not only in safari). If you need to reuse it, in a visible img tag, then you can use CSS to resize it. I don't see why it will be tiny if you set proper viewBox. The real caveat is that it will taint the canvas in IE<Edge